# In Windows shell, How do I echo the date of the oldest file in a directory?

Tags: shell, batch-file, recursion, cmd

I have the following code (which works well) in a batch file for listing directories recursively with a filecount for each directory, but besides what I already have, I need to know the date of the oldest file in current directory, where it says `I_NEED_YEAR_HERE`, how can I do that?

```
@echo off

setlocal disableDelayedExpansion
if "%~1"=="" (call :recurse ".") else call :recurse %1
exit /b

:recurse
setlocal
set fileCnt=0
for /d %%D in ("%~1\*") do call :recurse "%%~fD"
for /f %%F in ('dir /b /a-d "%~1\*" 2^>nul ^| find /v /c ""') do (
  set /a fileCnt+=%%F 
)
echo %~f1 has %fileCnt% files and the oldest file is from year I_NEED_YEAR_HERE
( 
  endlocal
  set /a fileCnt+=%fileCnt%
)

exit /b
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET "sourcedir=U:\sourcedir"
PUSHD "%sourcedir%"


setlocal DISABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
SET /a grand=0
if "%~1"=="" (call :recurse ".") else call :recurse %1
ECHO Total=%grand%

POPD
GOTO :eof

:recurse
setlocal
for /d %%D in ("%~1\*") do call :recurse "%%~fD"
set /a fileCnt=0
SET "oldest="
for /f "delims=" %%F in ('dir /b /a-d /o-d "%~1\*" 2^>nul') do (
  set /a fileCnt+=1
  IF NOT DEFINED oldest FOR %%O IN ("%~1\%%~nxF") DO SET "oldest=%%~tO %~1\%%~nxF"
)
echo %~f1 has %fileCnt% files and the oldest file is from year %oldest:~6,4% %oldest%
(
 ENDLOCAL
 SET /a grand=%grand%+%fileCnt%
)

exit /b

GOTO :EOF
```

Slightly reformatted to suit my testing on test directory u:\sourcedir.

I set `oldest` to both date and filename. Selecting the required data is a matter of appropriate substringing, and it would need to be gated on #files <> 0.

Intriguingly, `SET /a grand=%grand%+%fileCnt%` worked whereas `SET /a grand+=%fileCnt%` failed...

Answer (score 0):

With your code you'll have to add a new `FOR` loop and enable the `Delayedexpansion`

Something like that will work :

```
@echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
if "%~1"=="" (call :recurse ".") else call :recurse %1
exit /b

:recurse
setlocal
set fileCnt=0
for /d %%D in ("%~1\*") do call :recurse "%%~fD"
for /f %%F in ('dir /b /a-d "%~1\*" 2^>nul ^| find /v /c ""') do (
  set /a fileCnt+=%%F
)    
pushd  "%~f1" 2>nul
set "$date="
for /f "delims=" %%x in ('dir /b/o-d') do (set $date=%%~tx
set $date=!$date:~6,4!)
popd
echo %~f1 has %fileCnt% files and the oldest file is from year !$date!
( 
 endlocal 
  set /a fileCnt+=%fileCnt%
)

exit /b
```

You can use this one with 2 `FOR` loop which is more compact and more easy :

```
@echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /b/ad/s "%1"') do (
pushd "%%a"
set $c=0
for /f %%x in ('dir /b/o-d/a-d') do (
set "$date=%%~tx"
set "$date=!$date:~6,4!"
set /a $c+=1)
popd
if !$c!==0 set $date=[Null]
echo %%a has !$c! files and the oldest file is from year !$date!
)
```